# C++ class template as function return type

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

I'm working on a little project to understand how C++ templates work.
Basically, I have something like:

```
class Base{
public:
    MyOperation<Base> operate(Base x){ return MyOperation<Base>(x); } //error here
};

//...

template<class B>
class MyOperation : public Base{
public:
    B b;
    MyOperation(B b_){ b = b_; }
};
```

When I try compiling my program, I get an error (Error C2143, missing ';' before '<'). Is it because I can't have MyOperation as return type of funcion operate()?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this `template(class B)` correct syntax?

Comment: The compiler should show you the line. Generally if an error mentions syntax, you've messed up syntax. Here, you've got `template(class B)` when it should be `template<class B>`. May be your pseudocode though, otherwise I'd post this an answer.

Comment: `Base` cannot _see_ `MyOperation` because it's defined _after_ `Base`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it correctly in my project, `template<class B>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for declaring a template is `template<class B>` (or equivalently, `template<typename B>`).

Also there is a circular reference: `Base` references `MyOperation` (return type and inside the `operate` function). So `MyOperation` would need to be defined before `Base`.

But `MyOperation` also references `Base` (base class).

For the base class, and for the use inside a function, a full definition is needed. But for the return type, an *incomplete type* is enough. So `MyOperation` would need to be predeclared before `Base`, like:

```
template<class B> class MyOperation;
```

And in addition, `operate()` needs to be defined (not declared) outside of `class Base { ... }`, after the definition of `MyOperation`. The correct code would be:

```
// pre-declaration of MyOperation
template<class B> class MyOperation;

// definition of Base class
class Base {
public:
    // declaration of Base::operate member function
    // MyOperation<Base> is incomplete type here
    MyOperation<Base> operate(Base x);
};   

// definition of MyOperation class template
template<class B>
class MyOperation : public Base{
public:
    B b;
    MyOperation(B b_){ b = b_; }
};

// definition ofBase::operate member function
inline MyOperation<Base> Base::operate(Base x) {
    return MyOperation<Base>(x);
}
```

`Base::operate` needs to be inline if the definition is in a header file, otherwise there will be multiple linker symbols if the header is included by multiple source files.

If it is not inline (better if it is a large function), then the definition should go in a source file.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new at programming so I didn't think about circular references.